# How to force TLS renegotiation in Jetty 7?

Tags: authentication, servlets, ssl, jetty

Is there a way to trigger SSL renegotiation in a servlet running on Jetty 7?  I've seen several examples of configuration in the web.xml file but nothing in code.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: For what purpose? Change cipher spec? Request client certificate? Re-key?

Comment: Requesting a client certificate for a single URL

Comment: Oh, and I'm running Java 1.7